# how to convert or replace parameter into description if my data more than 100

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i have problem to declare parameter description in the report. If my id have more than 100 description. How to display the data in the report?.

For example i have list of company. i want to display name of company in the title.
My parameter is $P{companyid}.
every id have a description. that is name of company. but the data have more than hundred. how can i show the name in my label parameter.

How to do that?.

Please help me.:(

Comment: what i mean is i have parameter name is P{companyid}. When i key in that  parameter P{companyid}, i want that parameter automatically direct convert into description. For example when i enter the P{companyid}= 1 then it will be 'SPA SDN BHD'.P{companyid}= 2 then it will be 'PELANGI SDN BHD'. P{companyid}= 3 then it will be 'SAMUDERA SDN BHD'. i have try use the condition but the problem is my record company have more than hundred. how can i convert all the id into description?.

Comment: Please help me.I am in a deadlock and upset. i don't know how  fix this problem.:( :( :(

Comment: You can write [scriptlet](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to join to the company table in your SQL statement and add the description field to your select statement.  Then display the description field in the text box in your report.